# Wacom Intuos 5 Art Small isn't detected by Wacom Properties window

Tags: drivers, tablet, wacom

recently i buy a wacom intuos 2015 and works perfectly on windows 10 but in Ubuntu when i plug the tablet the system doesn't detect it, so i searched and installed the drivers and now the pressure is detected, the main problem is that in the wacom properties window in system settings puts that the tablet is disconnected, i need this window to set the express keys of the tablet and modify the pressure.

Answer (score 0):

You can try updating your libwacom [1]. That may or may not be successful for a variety of reasons.

If that does not work try using xsetwacom [2]. Note your buttons will most likely be numbered 1,9,8 and 3.[3]

[1] http://linuxwacom.sourceforge.net/wiki/index.php/Libwacom 
[2] http://linuxwacom.sourceforge.net/wiki/index.php/Tablet_Configuration 
[3] https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=126282

Comment: I updated my wacom drivers, but the gnome-wacom-properties still not detecting it.